# How Can I Clone a Camera Source DirectShow Filter?

Tags: com, directshow

I'm doing some stereoscopic work which means I have need to work with two instances of various filters (i.e. a camera source that receives an IP stream), and this is proving not to be trivial.

I even tried copying the IPCamfilter.ax to IPCamfilter.ax and manually making new CLSID entries in the reg, and the clone shows up, but won't work. Any ideas?

Should I edit the clone filters binary to change its CLSID and then register it? Or is there a simple way to use GraphEdit to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you work with two cameras or with one camera and you wanna have two pictures.

In the first case, there are some filters which work just with one connected device (in case for e.g. firewire, cameras have to be connected to two different controllers).

In the latter case, you can use the `Infinite Pin Tee Filter` to get two streams of the one device. You can test that in GraphEdit as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in COM that prevents you creating two instances of the same clsid, so you're solving the wrong problem by trying to change the clsid. There must be something in the filter internals that prevents multiple use in the same process.

If you can't get access to the source to fix it, you could have two capture graphs in separate processes and then use a bridge of some sort to combine the two outputs in a third graph (or in your application).

G

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the limitation is in the Capture Source filters that I'm using. For example, UScreenCapture creates a reg key where it keeps its settings so a cloned filter would use the same reg key. I think I need my own Capture Source .dll that hosts the the capture source filter graph.

Answer (score 0):

SplitCam is a freeware virtual video clone and video driver for connecting several applications to a single video capture source. Usually, if you have a camera connected to your PC, you cannot use it in more than one application at the same time, and there is no standard Windows options that makes it possible. Split [Camera](http://www.etechreviews.net/sigma-dp2-camera-for-art-enthusiasts/) allows you to easily multiply your video source in any conferencing software like ICQ, Yahoo, MSN Messenger, or whatever.

Video Processing Filter is a powerful transform filter that allows rotate the video in 90, 180, and 270 degrees ,keep aspect ratio when rotated the video in 90 and 270 degrees , flip the video, convert a RGB video stream to Grayscale and invert color. Support rotate the video in 90, 180, and 270 degrees in any Directshow base application. Support keep aspect ratio when rotated the video in 90 and 270 degrees.